# Bad request when trying to map a js array to List<CustomClass>,Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to sent a request along with an array to the Spring MVC Controller, and hope to map it into a List of Custom class:

```
$.ajax({
            url:contextPath+ "/auth/manage/getAuthList.do",
            type: "POST",
            data: {subjectList:subjectList}
 .....
}
```

and the controller is like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAuthList.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
  public JsonResult getAuthorizedList(@RequestParam List<Subject> subjectList, HttpSession session) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, SQLException {
```

**But when the requests are sent, I got a bad request.**

```
Required List parameter 'subjectList' is not present
```

I have also tried using `Subject[]` instead of `List` but it has the same bad request(need parameter Array but not provided).

//subjectList is like:

```
[{
    btId:9
    btName:"tx3"
    btNameCN:"YYY",
    serviceId:1,
    subjectId:9401,
    suebjectNameCN:"XXX"
},
    btId:9
    btName:"tx3"
    btNameCN:"YYY2",
    serviceId:1,
    subjectId:9402,
    suebjectNameCN:"XXX2"
}
]
```

This is my `Subject` class

```
public class Subject implements Serializable{

    private int subjectId;
    private String subjectNameCN;
    private int btId;
    private String btName;
    private String btNameCN;
    private int serviceId;

    public Subject(int subjectId, String subjectNameCN, int btId,
            String btName, String btNameCN, int serviceId) {
        super();
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
        this.subjectNameCN = subjectNameCN;
        this.btId = btId;
        this.btName = btName;
        this.btNameCN = btNameCN;
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }


    public int getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }
    public void setServiceId(int serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    public int getSubjectId() {
        return subjectId;
    }
    public void setSubjectId(int subjectId) {
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
    }

    public String getSubjectNameCN() {
        return subjectNameCN;
    }
    public void setSubjectNameCN(String subjectNameCN) {
        this.subjectNameCN = subjectNameCN;
    }

    public int getBtId() {
        return btId;
    }
    public void setBtId(int btId) {
        this.btId = btId;
    }

    public String getBtName() {
        return btName;
    }
    public void setBtName(String btName) {
        this.btName = btName;
    }

    public String getBtNameCN() {
        return btNameCN;
    }
    public void setBtNameCN(String btNameCN) {
        this.btNameCN = btNameCN;
    }

    //please discard this two method since it is wrong getter/setter but legacy ones
    public int getserviceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }
    public void setserviceId(int serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

}
```

## Updated:

try replacing @RequestParam to @RequestBody, get a 415

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `@RequestParam` with `@RequestBody` annotation.

`@RequestParam` is for GET request parameters, while you are providing data as the POST request body.

Comment: Tried, becomes a 415 error!  please check my updated question

Comment: Try adding Content-Type and Accept headers to the request and setting consumes and produces @RequestMapping parameters to 'application/json'